# Excel - Sum row conditionally based on employee name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice

I need to create a sheet that will allow me to summarise the total cost per employee depending on their name. So, in the following sample, I would want to have a column which summarises the costs for "JACOB" and another column for "LISA" in addition to the total column.

Snippet of active sheet:

[image: Snippet of active sheet]

I've been trying to use a sumIf with this dataset (as shown below), but I keep receiving an Error 504 (within LibreOffice Calc) or a #VALUE! error within MS Excel.

SUMIF error message/code:

[image: SUMIF error message/code]

I was wondering what I was doing wrong in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Excel formula solution.

1] Criteria put in range `P2:P4`

2] In "Total" `Q2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMIF(D:L,P2,E:M)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen the "~" sign in excel application. Is that allowed?
Consider using three helper columns instead with a content like

=if(d2="Jacob";e2;0)

=if(h2="Jacob";i2;0)

=if(l2="Jacob";m2;0)

Make "total amount" the sum of those three helper columns.

Then the total amount would be limited to the sum of the columns preceded by the word "Jacob".

Comment: The ~ is an escape character for other escape characters. So if you for example want to find the character "?" in a cell text, you use ~? in the formula.

Comment: MiG, thank you!